# AFIncrementalStore simple fetch terminating with a crash

Tags: ios, core-data, afincrementalstore

I'm setting up a very simple NSIncrementalStore example using AFIncrementalStore.

The idea is to setup a NSManagedObjectContext in the AppDelegate (using the ordinary template provided by Apple, with changes for my IncrementalStore), do a fetch with no predicate or sort descriptor and NSLog the one fetched entity object.

Everything works great until I ask for any entity attribute. It crashes with the following message:

```
2013-07-22 16:34:46.544 AgendaWithAFIncrementalStore[82315:c07] -[_NSObjectID_id_0 eventoId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x838b060
2013-07-22 16:34:46.545 AgendaWithAFIncrementalStore[82315:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSObjectID_id_0 eventoId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x838b060'
```

My xcdatamodeld is correctly setted up. The NSManagedObject class is generated and imported on the delegate. When I do a breakpoint before the NSLog I can see the fetched objects IDs. The webservice is giving me back the correct data.

My AppDelegate code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ... 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(remoteFetchHappened:) name:AFIncrementalStoreContextDidFetchRemoteValues object:self.managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                          entityForName:@"Agenda" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription;
    fetchRequest.predicate = nil;
    NSError *error;

    [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    return YES;
}

// Handle the notification posted when the webservice returns objects
- (void)remoteFetchHappened:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSArray *fetchResult = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:@"AFIncrementalStoreFetchedObjectIDs"];
    Agenda *agenda = (Agenda *)[fetchResult lastObject];

    // THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS...
    NSLog(@"Agenda: %@", agenda.eventoId);
}
```

Any ideas on how to make this piece of code return the attribute I'm asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFNetworking is giving you managed object IDs, that is, instances of `NSManagedObjectID`. You can't look up managed object property values on that-- you have to get the managed object for the ID first. That's what `_NSObjectID_id_0` means in the error message-- you're trying to get 
`eventoId` on an `NSManagedObjectID`, and it has no idea what that is.

You get the managed object by looking it up in the managed object context. Something like

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObject *myObject = [context existingObjectWithID:objectID error:error];
if (myObject != nil) {
    // look up attribute values on myObject
}
```